# website hosting and calling web service from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services, hosting

I am learning android and currently i done database operation using calling web service which i have written in php and from that php it returns data in json format.

I done this operation in my computer using WAMP server and from android i used localhost ip address which is 10.0.2.2 then i accessed the necessary files using it access the database stored in my computer and returns data in json format.

But now i want to do it in Internet i mean to say now i want to put my php code and database somewhere on Internet and access from it.

I don't know how can i do it.

I am completely new to all these things.

Thanks in advance to clear all the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a PHP webhosting from any renowned vendors like Godaddy.com . Register yourself a domain name of your choice. Buy both of them as a combined package and they will help it configure for you.

After making neccessary payments, you will be getting a cPanel login information. Inside the panel you can find phpMyAdmin/MySQL Wizard (where you can create your database and tables which you have used for your application in the localhost).

Now change all the ip address (`http://10.0.2.2/phpfiles/phpwebservice.php`) in your Android code to `http://www.yournewwebsitename.com/phpfiles/phpwebservice.php`

Now your app will be able to access the remote URL.

Comment: can we do it using free website hosting?

Comment: I don't think its a good idea, because they are not *reliable*

Comment: ya but as a starting i just want to check. here i created my domain niravkamani.webuda.com i also created my database over there but now i am unable to understand where can i put my php files and how to access it?

Comment: You must be having a control panel right ? Just login with it and drop all your PHP files, also don't forget to configure the database.

Comment: ya i am having cPanel but there are lots of options i am unable to understand.I configured my database.I mean to say i am having my database username and password and other things.But how to load all php files?If anything else remains in database configuration?

Comment: In the cPanel home page, you will see File Manager, click it and there you will get a Windows Explorer like view. On the top you can find `Upload` button. So make use of to upload all your PHP files.

Comment: ok i done uploading of all the files now i mean to say all the files are accessible using http://www.niravkamani.webuda.com/db_connect.php or not?if i uploaded file called db_connect.php

Comment: now how can i access all the files? i tried to use niravkamani.webuda.com/db_connect.php then it shows error.

Comment: Try accessing using complete document URL e.g. http://www.example.com/services/login.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, Do i need to buy the domain to access the php files from my code? I have my code locally and everything is working fine. I then copied the same file to GoDaddy to trying to give GoDaddy php file and i am not getting any response. Can you please check this? https://my.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/Why-i-am-unable-to-access-public-html-files-from-a-program/td-p/134596

Comment: @Uday, It's been years I answered to this post. Let me reply you there on godaddy community panel.